# Slicing a for loop in Django

Tags: python, django, for-loop, slice

My objective is to iterate through the model DeathDay posts that can be created through the admin (which contain several names and surnames) and display the last three persons that have been registered in such a model in the homepage that correspond to today. At the moment, I'm using a ListView function and it allows me to paste every name and surname that have been registered today. However, I tried to use the slice method but in such a case it finds that the first three elements of the list have no been created today and it does not show any result on my template.

Template:

```
{% for post in object_list %}
    {% if date == post.daytoday %}
        <b>{{ post.daynome }} {{ post.daycognome }}</b> </br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Models.py:

```
class DeathDay(models.Model):
    daynome = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    daycognome = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    daynascita = models.DateField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    daymorte = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    daytoday = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    dayluogo = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What is your model? Where is your view code? Last 3 with regard to what?

Comment: Post your `views` and `models` code. Only then people will be able to help you.

Comment: I have learned from my mistake and I have posted a new version can you help me guys? @schwobaseggl

Answer (score 0):

```
object_list = List.objects.last()
```

gives you the last object created

Comment: Which would then be terribly misnomered.